# Finding the intersection point of $x^2 +y^2 = 4$ and $(x,y) = (t- \sin(t), 1-\cos(t))$

Tags: calculus

$x^2 +y^2 = 4$
and  $(x,y) = (t- \sin(t), 1-\cos(t))$

Find the exact intersection point in terms of $t$, no calculator allowed. This seems like an easy algebra problem, but it is throwing me off.

$(t- \sin(t))^2$ + $(1- \cos(t))^2$ = $4$

$t^2 - 2t\sin(t) + \sin^2(t) + 1 - 2\cos(t) + \cos^2(t) = 4$

$t^2 - 2t\sin(t) - 2\cos(t) = 2$

How do I solve this from here?

I am supposed to use this information to then calculate the length of the $(x,y)$ curve, but I know how to do that once I find the upper bound, which is the intersection point.

Comment: You're right: it's not an easy problem. [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=t%5E2+-+2t%5Csin%28t%29+-+2%5Ccos%28t%29+%3D+2) struggles to find exact forms for these solutions. I highly suspect that it was a typo, and the first coordinate was supposed to be $1 - \sin(t)$, making the second curve another circle.

Comment: The problem on the page specifically mentions it is a cycloid, and the function they mentioned is a cycloid.

Comment: Ah, then I am most certainly wrong! I still don't see how you're supposed to solve this equation without a calculator that a CAS can do nothing with.

Comment: FWIW, solving your last equation numerically gives $t = 2.132020145945943$, from which $x = 1.2854157450930646$ and $y = 1.532222686905151$.